# Is there any JSF Select Time Zone component out there?

Tags: jsf-2

I have been looking for this for a while and haven't found it.   It is surprisingly complicated as shown in this old [IceFaces tutorial](http://www.scribd.com/doc/54922179/14/Step-1-%E2%80%93-Basic-JSF-TimeZone-Application).

What is needed is a UIInput component that will set a **java.util.TimeZone** property, allowing the user to select it from a map or a list on the screen.  Before I dive in to write one for myself -- does anyone know of an available component that does this?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`<h:selectOneMenu>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/selectOneMenu.html) to represent a dropdown list. Use [`<f:selectItems>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/selectItems.html) to feed it with a `E[]`, `List<E>`, `SelectItem[]` or `List<SelectItem>` as value.

Here's how it can look like at its simplest:

```java
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean implements Serializable {

    private String timeZoneID; // +getter +setter
    private String[] timeZoneIDs; // +getter only

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        timeZoneIDs = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
        // You may want to store it in an application scoped bean instead.
    }

    public void submit() {
        System.out.println("Selected time zone: " + TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZoneID));
    }

    // ...
}
```

with this view:

```html
<h:form>
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.timeZoneID}" required="true">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="Select timezone..." />
        <f:selectItems value="#{bean.timeZoneIDs}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.submit}" />
    <h:messages/>
</h:form>
```

If you want to make it a fullworthy `TimeZone` property, you'd need to bring in a `@FacesConverter(forClass=TimeZone.class)` which should be pretty straightforward enough.

Comment: I did this much already in a composite component that I am using in the development stage of my project.  However you will notice there are over 600 available IDs from the Java runtime (they need to be sorted as well) and it is a bit much for a selectOneMenu component.   What I was looking for for deployment is something that showed a map that would make it more intuitive.   At this point I am pretty sure there is no JSF component out there; now I am looking for an open-source JavaScript package that does this to base my component on.

Comment: You could use an autosuggest component from PrimeFaces or RichFaces.

Comment: Hey that's an interesting idea.   Although I won't have the graphic I wanted I could at least have something more user-friendly for deployment.  Thanks for the tip.